# How do I generate a Map of Map of List (Map<String, Map<Enum, List<String>>>) in java using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Given:

```
enum Food{
FRUITS, VEGGIES;
}

Map<String, List<String>> basketMap = new HashMap<>();
basketMap .put("bucket1", Arrays.asList("apple", "banana"));
basketMap .put("bucket2", Arrays.asList("orange", "kiwi"));
basketMap .put("bucket3", Arrays.asList("banana", "orange"));
```

Need to generate a Map of map of list(populte fruitBaskerMap)

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>> fruitBasketMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Final output:

```
fruitBasketMap:
[
bucket1, [Food.FRUITS, {"apple", "banana"}],
bucket2, [Food.FRUITS, {"orange", "kiwi"}],
bucket3, [Food.FRUITS, {"banana", "orange"}]
]
```

I tried the below (but was not successful)

```
fruitBasketMap = basketMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.toMap(Food.FRUITS,
            Collectors.toList(Map.Entry::getValue())
        )
    )
);
```

Can somebody let me know how do I do that?

Comment: What is expected result of your code? How should that map be filled? Will it ever contain any VEGGIES?

Comment: No you don't need to generate a `Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>`. You need to create a class, and change the type to `Map<String, ClassType>`

Comment: @Pshemo it will never contain VEGGIES, it contains only FRUITS. just updated the post and added the final output of what is expected.

Comment: @smac89 there is no scope to add a new class.

Comment: Are you really limited to Java 8 or methods from Java 9 or above are also available? For instance `Map.of` would let you write collector like `Collectors
                        .toMap(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                entry -> Map.of(Food.FRUITS, entry.getValue())
                        )`

Comment: If you are limited to Java 8 instead of `entry -> Map.of(...)` you can use `entry -> { 
                                    Map<Food, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
                                    map.put(Food.FRUITS, entry.getValue());
                                    return map;
                                }`

Comment: OR you can create some utility method like `static Map<Food, List<String>> createMap(Food key, List<String> value){
        Map<Food, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(Food.FRUITS, value);
        return map;
    }` and use it as `entry -> createMap(Food.FRUITS, entry.getValue())`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you very much one of the solution you provided worked out for me.
Solution:
```fruitBasketMap = basketMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> {
                            Map<Food, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put(Food.FRUITS, entry.getValue());
                            return map;
                        }
                    )
        );```

Comment: @PrashanthGajula There's another solution using `groupingBy`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353011/10584605).

Answer (score 1):

This implementation seems to be working (using Java 9 Map.of):

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> fruitBasketMap = basketMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), Map.of(Food.FRUITS, e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Output of the test:

```
{
bucket2={FRUITS=[orange, kiwi]}, 
bucket3={FRUITS=[banana, orange]}, 
bucket1={FRUITS=[apple, banana]}
}
```

Comment: `This implementation seems to be working` - It will work indeed .

Comment: `Map.of` was introduced in Java 9, question is tagged with Java 8 so I am not sure if we can use it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick in `Java 8+` way:

```
fruitBasketMap = 
    basketMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                                 toMap(e -> Food.FRUITS, Entry::getValue)));
```

---

The collector above works in the following way:

1. Groups the elements by their keys, thus the keys remain the same as in the original map.
2. Collects the entries into a new map with

   - key: Food.FRUITS (constant for all entries)
   - value: the original value (list of strings)

Answer (score 0):

This would work with Java 8

```
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> collect = basketMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(basketMapEntry -> basketMapEntry.getKey(),
                        basketMapEntry -> basketMapEntry.getValue().stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        item -> type.get(item)
                                        )
                                )
                )
        );
```

I am using the groupingBy collector to group the list of items based on the enum. 
Assumption is that there would a Map to know the value of Food based on the entry. Something like:

```
Map<String, Food> type = new HashMap<>();
        type.put("apple", Food.FRUITS);
        type.put("banana", Food.FRUITS);
        type.put("orange", Food.FRUITS);
        type.put("kiwi", Food.FRUITS);
        type.put("kiwi", Food.FRUITS);
        type.put("potato", Food.VEGGIES);
        type.put("carrot", Food.VEGGIES);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in Java-8 way itself. Try the below one. Since the inner map will always have single entry, you can use `singletonMap`

```java
Map<String, Map<Food, List<String>>> result = basketMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> Collections.singletonMap(Food.FRUITS, entry.getValue())));
```